# Как изменить цвет JButton во время нажатия

Tags: java, swing

Есть какие-то методы позволяющие изменить цвет `JButton` во время нажатия? Если же нет, то как это возможно сделать? Пытался найти, но ничего достаточно простого не нашёл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class ShyButton extends JButton {
    private final Color pressedColor = Color.RED;

    public ShyButton() {
        this(null);
    }

    public ShyButton(String text) {
        super(text);
        super.setContentAreaFilled(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        if (getModel().isPressed()) {
            g.setColor(pressedColor);
        }
        else {
            g.setColor(getBackground());
        }
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
        super.paintComponent(g);
    }
}

public class Demo extends JFrame {
    public Demo() {
        super("Demo");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        add(new ShyButton("Click me"));

        pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo window = new Demo();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```